# Copy Row down based on # of rows in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've copied and modified this macro to copy row 3 (columns A to AZ) in sheet "Margin" down as many rows as there is data in sheet "Raw_Data" but I get a

> runtime 424 error.

```
Sub EndRow_Stuff()

    Dim EndRow As Long

    ' sets EndRow to last cell in column A's row number
    EndRow = Raw_Data.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' autofill to range set by EndRow in Sheet1
    Margin.Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:AZ" & EndRow), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) • What is `Raw_Data` and `Margin`? Did you create at VBA-Name for these in the VB Editor or are these just the sheet names on the tab. If these are the names on the tabe you must use `Worksheets("Raw_Data")` instead. Please clarify.

Comment: Raw_Data and Margin are sheet names

Comment: Yes but there are 2 different naming systems. The VBA code name (which you used) and the tab name in Excel. Since both naming systems are completely independent the tab name and the code name of a sheet is not the same. If you rename a tab it doesn't change its code name. So please clarify.